# Components not showing up in Vue DevTools

Tags: vue.js

Has anyone experienced this problem? I'm using Vue Devtools but can't inspect any components on a count of none are showing up. No Root component or anything. Pretty much just a blank DevTools. I'm new to Vue so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. I'm using the webpack cli template and haven't implemented any Vue Router stuff yet. Nothing comes up when searching for components either. I'm assuming it's something in these 3 files?

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
var db = firebase.database();

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created: function() {
    // Import firebase data 
    var quizzesRef = db.ref('quizzes');
    quizzesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
      vm.quizzes = snapshot.val();
    });
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
        authenticated: false,
        quizzes: {},
        resources: []
    }
  },
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <resource-info></resource-info>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import ResourceInfo from './components/ResourceInfo'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Navbar,
    ResourceInfo
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Index.html (Omitted header)

```
<body>
    <div id="app" class="container-fluid"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: ""
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You're serving the files from an http server, correct?  The Vue DevTools won't work with file-based serving.

Comment: I'm using `npm run dev`.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I get exactly that behaviour in Vivaldi, but it works in plain Chrome... I'm posting that to both the vuedevtools and Vivaldi groups...

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue and here's what fixed it for me:

Ensure `Allow access to file URLs` in the chrome extension settings (`chrome://extensions`) is enabled. Restart Chrome.

Open the Vue DevTools extension and click the Refresh button on the top right after opening a Vue component on the page.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This actually fully broke it for me.

Comment: Thank you! It worked rgeat for me... and no need to restart chrome, just new tab is enough!

Comment: nice...! I don't know the reason but it works

Comment: @jarrodwhitley maybe you just need to reopen your tab.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are using `vue-cli` and I assume it is running in dev mode (`npm run dev`).

Obviously it will not work after you build the production app using `npm run build` and serve from the `dist` folder.

Assuming you have taken care of the above, did you install the `Vue.js devtools` recently in Chrome? If so, your browser might need a restart. I think I had to do it when I installed Vue devtools for the first time.

After all that, you should start seeing your components in "Vue" tab of developer tools. You might see **Anonymous component** for some components, but all you need is `name: app` which is something you are already doing in your *App.vue* component.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue! Not much to find scratching around for help, but this worked for me:

change the webpack.config.js setting for NODE_ENV: '"production"' to NODE_ENV: '"development"'

Seems almost too obvious but the rendered Vue app(s) then appeared like magic showing all the object goodness!