# Why is my vue component not showing up in vue-devtools and rendered as a data-v-xxx div?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

The problem I currently have is that my Vue component does not render how I expected it would.

I'll attempt to clarify what I mean by this as I realise it's quite vague:

Currently I have a Vue component which I render using:

```js
if (document.querySelector('.dishes')) {
    Vue.component(
        'DishesList',
        require('../components/DishesList').default
    );

    new Vue({
        el: '#dishes',
    });
}
```

This does actually work as the content specified in this component is being loaded. The HTML that results from loading it is:

```
<div class="dishes">
    <div id="dishes">
        <div data-v-xxxxxx>
            .....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However it's not what I expected it would be. Whenever I've used Vue before, the component shown in the HTML would still be something like:

```
<div class="dishes">
    <div id="dishes">
        <dishes-list></dishes-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `dishes-list` component is like this (I filtered out some stuff):

```
<template>
    .....
</template>

<script>
    import Dish from "./Dish";

    export default {
        name: "DishesList",
        props: ["categories"],
        data: function () {
            return {
                search:'',
                order: {}
            }
        },
        components: {
            Dish,
        },
        methods: {

        },
        mounted() {

        },
        computed: {
        }

    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .category {
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
</style>
```

This also results in the Vue devtools not being able to see my `dishes-list` component. The only thing that is recognized is the component `<root>` with nothing in it. My question is: what causes Vue to load a component as `<div data-v-xxxx>` instead of the `<dishes-list>` that I've seen before?

Hope this all make sense. If I can do anything to clarify the question please do tell me as I'm quite new to Stackoverflow and I'm trying to make the best of it. I'm also quite new with Vue, so try to take that in mind if you know the answer.

Comment: Can you paste part of your DishesList component? `<dishes-list>` is not a valid HTML tag (unless you are using WebComponents, which is not something that happens by default with Vue). Your component likely renders as a `<div>`.

Comment: I added some information on the dishes component, I removed the html though I'm not sure if I should include some of that as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my specific situation, so I'll explain what was wrong and how I fixed it in case anyone else every comes across the same issue:

The problem I had was that I had another vue component rendering at a much higher level in the dom. To illustrate this:

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div id="dishes">
                    <div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This div with id=app is running an 'instance' (if you can call it that) of vue and therefore the dev-tools stop searching for any other instances. In my case, as the component wasn't a direct child of this div, my real component simply wasn't spotted. So in short, if anyone ever comes a problem like this: check if your not loading any other components that might interfer with the one you want to see in your devtools.

*I've edited the question to better reflect what it was I was trying to ask, but I would still like to thank everyone that responded as you did put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inspecting the HTML in the browser's *Elements* tab then it is correct to see `<div data-v-xxxxxx>`, that is normal.

The `data-v-xxxxxx` part just indicates that the component uses scoped CSS.

When the HTML is first loaded into the browser it will contain the `<dishes-list></dishes-list>` tags. When you start Vue with `new Vue(...)` it will parse the template inside element `#dishes` and replace its contents. The new contents will typically be standard HTML elements, the component names will be gone.

To see this for yourself, try disabling Vue by commenting out the lines that create the instance. You should see the `<dishes-list></dishes-list>` in the HTML. Seeing that element is just an indication that Vue hasn't run that template.

Comment: That's good to know, but I'm still left wandering why vuedevtoola doesn't recognize the dishes-list component. Do you happen to know what might have caused this? It's so weird to me because as you've mentioned, the template is in fact being rendered properly.

Comment: @killermi200 There's not a lot to go on here. There are some suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186095, but none look like a perfect fit for your symptoms. Restarting the browser is worth a shot. I'm assuming you're on recent versions of both Vue and the devtools but if either are old versions it could be that. Also, try right-clicking on your list in the UI and look for *'Inspect Vue Component'* in the browser's context-menu, see what that does.